# How to read configuration file in COM+ server

Tags: c#, .net, com+

I have a COM+ server (project output dll) which is consumed from a proxy (I guess this is called client applcation and runs under dllhost.exe). The COM+ server runs through a server console application (project output exe) which itself runs as a service.

I need to read a configuration file in COM+ server (dll). I do not know

1. where should I have the config file and under what name? One config
   file exists for proxy with name dllhost.exe.config.
2. how to read this config file in COM+ server?
3. how to have my custom configration in file?

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516261/com-server-configuration-with-custom-configurationsection) here, but I cannot figure out what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) In the COM+ application root directory you must place two files:

- `application.manifest`
- `application.config`

2) Your `application.manifest` file can have just this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
</assembly>
```

3) Your `application.config` file must be similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myPropertyName" value="myPropertyValue"></add>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

4) In the COM+ sorce code, you can use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myPropertyName"]
```

in order to read a configuration property (if you are using C#).

**NOTE**: the "application root directory" can be determined by using the COM+ administration console (`dcomcnfg.exe`), "Activation" tab.

Comment: Precisely what I have been looking for. I have tested it on development machine and want to test it on server. Under "Activation" tab on server "Applicatin Root Directory" is blank. What does it mean and what to do? Anyways, you get my vote.

Comment: When you register your COM+ components by executing `regsvcs.exe`, you can use the option `/appdir:<path>` for specifying a concrete
directory for your application. In that case you will see that path in the Activation tab of the administration console. If it is blank for you, problably you are not using that option and Windows is installing the application at the default location (I don't remember at this moment where it was).